# enabling XML comments in C++ in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

How can one enable/achieve XML comments for C++ methods ala C# and VB in Visual Studio 2010? It appears this functionality isn't enabled/available by default.

Targeting initially managed C++ projects.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

This is not supported in C++ for VS2010.

Comment: you should remove this answer

Comment: @Willem D'haeseleer would be nice to but you can't delete an accepted answer.

Comment: well that sucks, but that shouldn't keep you from striking it through it or, even better, fixing it !

Answer (score 6):

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Generate XML Documentation Files.

You will have to manually add all your xml documentation (/// doesn't auto-create a summary template for you). Also doesn't support paramref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173501.aspx

Comment: thanks for this answer. I guess the root of the question was whether VS actuall can auto-create that template when typing the triple slash in a C++ code file.

Comment: @p.campbell: You could try something like QuickCode, although I don't know if they have a VS2010 plugin. They do have a 2005 and 2008 plugin that might just work. From what I understand, code snippets don't work in C++, but QuickCode does.

Answer (score 2):

To auto complete xml documentation stubs when /// is typed try [CppTripleSlash - xml doc comments for c++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tcbhat.CppTripleSlash-xmldoccommentsforc) extension. It also has some basic intellisense to complete xml tags inside doc comments.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the old one, but everywhere I have looked everyone say's NOT SUPPORTED, need 3rd party tool or similar, none which is not the true. What you need to know is that XML Documentation is supported and is available in Visual Studio 2010, and there are only two things to know about it:

1. Docs/Previous Versions / Visual Studio / XML Documentation / Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms177227%28v%3dvs.90%29
2. In "C++ project properties / C/C++ / Output Files / Generate XML Documentation Files" set to "Yes (/doc)"

It will generate .xdc file for each source file containing documentation comments "///" and merge it into one .xml documentation file. And documentation works just fine later in other projects.